# Where can I find the schematics/CAD model for MacBook Pro's components?

Tags: macbook-pro, hardware-recommendation, customization, 3rd-party, design

**Device:** MacBook Pro (Retina, 13-inch, Mid 2014)

I'm looking for detailed schematics, preferably official Apple publications, describing and/or annotating the dimensions or other specifics of the components. I'm not looking for electrical layout diagrams.

My goal is to create an acrylic chassis inspired by the old iMacs to replace the aluminum. Any leads on the topic of this documentation is welcome, even if it's not everything.

The particular part I am interested in is pictured below:

[image]

Comment: I have the same problem, looked everywhere, found all the schematics for iApple devices but unfortuantely no Macbook: https://developer.apple.com/accessories/Accessory-Design-Guidelines.pdf - I will post it here, if I find anything.

Answer (score 1):

Apple isn't known for making their computer parts user replaceable or making their parts public, because of this I would think it would be highly unlikely Apple would publish CAD files/designs of parts. Here are some possibilities I can think of for finding a CAD file.

1. Find a patent.
   I'm not sure if Apple patented the chassis, but if they did you might be able to find the patent. If you're able to find it you could take the dimensions of it and turn it into a CAD file using a software like Blender, Fusion 360 or any other CAD application.
2. Contact a third party part manufacturer.
   There are multiple third parties that manufacture Apple computer parts. One example of those companies is [iFixIt](https://www.ifixit.com/). They provide some parts, kits, and guides for replacing certain computer parts. I took the time to find the parts you need. The bottom chassis is made up of two different parts. The first part is the [upper case assembly](https://www.ifixit.com/Store/Mac/MacBook-Pro-13-Inch-Retina-Late-2013-Mid-2014-Upper-Case-Assembly/IF123-033-1), the second is the [lower case assembly](https://www.ifixit.com/Store/Mac/MacBook-Pro-13-Inch-Retina-Late-2013-Mid-2014-Lower-Case/IF123-028-1). If you contact them and explain your situation to them, they might provide you with CAD files, this isn't the most likely though.
3. Using a ruler and CAD software.
   You've said you couldn't find any CAD files online so I won't mention that. That leaves one solution. Making your own CAD file, and just so you know, it's probably as complicated and time-consuming as it sounds. It's one thing just to make the part so it looks similar, but it's another thing to make it so it fits.

Good look finding/making the CAD file so you can make this part. I will look for a patent and make an update if I can find one.

P.S. Just so you know the part in the older macs is made out of plastic/rubber and not acrylic.

Comment: Thanks! I've gone the route of using calipers and producing drawings to send to a local CNC company. I don't want a Chinese manufacturer stealing "my" (Johny Ive's) designs. My neighbor is in my class at school, and his father is an apple exec, so I may ask him, as I know him quite well.

Answer (score 0):

Apple has a a program and guidelines designed to assist 3rd party manufacturers develop products for Apple Devices.

See:  [Designing Accessories](https://developer.apple.com/accessories)

Specific to what you’re looking for, see [Accessory Design Guidelines for Apple Devices](https://developer.apple.com/accessories/Accessory-Design-Guidelines.pdf)

> Includes detailed device dimensional drawings and important considerations for creating cases, covers, screen overlays, and camera attachments.